# 849, 352, 768, 493, 527 - Unusual number sequence problem

Tags: number-sequence

The sequence is: 849 352 768 493 527

This one has been puzzling me for days. I would appreciate any insight.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to Puzzle SE! If this is a puzzle you did not create yourself, remember to credit its original source.

Answer (score 13):

Look at them like this:

> $849\ 352\ 76 \quad 8\ 493\ 527$
>  
>  Notice the repeat?
>  
>  Next numbers are $684\ 935\ 276$

Further explanation:

> After the first 8 digits the sequence simply repeats. This is mildly obscured by them being grouped in lots of 3.

Comment: Couldn't see the wood for the trees. Thanks.

Comment: @bobble No snarkiness intended - thanks for edit!